# Kubuntu ISO and WUBI

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, wubi, iso

I've seen this question asked several times, but none of the answers seem to work for me. Disconnecting from the internet just causes WUBI to complain it can't connect. There must be a command line option for this.

I've downloaded the Kubuntu ISO and extracted WUBI from it. I want to use the 32 bit version (--32bit from CMD). It took a while to download the +1.2 gigabyte file and it's now torrenting it, taking longer to torrent it than the ISO took to download. The Wiki page for WUBI seems to be quite old and somewhat out of date.

The option to just download WUBI should be clear on the download pages, making the first large download of the ISO unnecessary

Here's my question (bonus points if you know what I'm gonna ask (somewhat annoyed at the waste of time), how do I force WUBI to use an ISO? Specifically Kubuntu 32bit.

Comment: WUBI is not recomended either mantained.

Comment: Which Kubuntu version do you want? 15.04 ? The Wubi version on 15.04 ISO is broken. It only accepts  the ISO for 14.10!  Best to avoid. If you want it anyway

Comment: ....(not recommended), you can only trust unofficial versions from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na maintained by ubuntuforums user hakuna_matata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this ( http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ ) and a flash drive.